# How do I create a percentage increase calculation in python?

Tags: python

I need to create a percentage increase in python.

My code is as follows:

(x = 135,000)

```py
x = x_1.strip()
  xspl = x.split(",")
  i=0
  for i in range(len(xspl)-1):
    if i == 0:
      xnum = xspl[i].join(xspl[i+1])
    else:
      xnum = xnum.join(xspl[i])
  calcnum2 = (int(xnum)-xPrev/xPrev)*100
  k=0
  for k in range(len(str((calcnum2)))):
    if str(calcnum2)[k] == '.': #looks for decimal place to make 2 d.p.
      subnum2 = str(calcnum2)[:k+3]
      break
    else:
      pass

  print(deceased,'(+',subnum2 + '%)')
  xPrev = int(xnum)
```

However, it does not make the number to 2 decimal places and actually outputs:

```
(+ 61356135100.0%)
```

Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: print(f'(+ {subnum2:.2f}%)')

Comment: (int(xnum)-xPrev/xPrev)*100  your numeric operator order doesn't seem correct. Perhaps (int(xnum)-xPrev)/xPrev * 100